# Red tint and flicker in Macbook LCD

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

For some time my aging 2008 Macbook's LCD has been "flickering" a bit but since it goes away after a while I've ignored it.

But in the last few days a red tint (might be pink - I am color blind :( ) has appeared in the bottom left corner that extends to about the half way point of the LCD. Initially it is quite red but after a little while it fades away though not completely, there is still a noticeable difference between the left and right corners if you look carefully.

It this a sign of the end? Is there anything I can do? My google search reveals similar red tints but with the entire screen.

Comment: Have you tried calibrating the screen?  It's located in System Preferences --> Display --> Calibrate.  Considering you're color blind, you might want to ask someone to help you with that.

Comment: Likely a sign of a dying GPU/screen/cable. Have you run AHT/some video stress program?

Comment: maybe see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338319/red-pixels-on-mojave-dark-mode#comment451527_338319

Answer (score -1):

It's the motherboard the video chip has came unsoldered known issues with them

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review