# In relation to the Red Pixels on Dark Mode Question, Here is something new to the issue

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen

[image]

From the photo taken above, whenever my cursor would hover over specific tabs, there would be thin white lines on the border surrounding the url bar as well as the search bar.

I have a video uploaded to my Youtube showing more effects I am assuming that would derive from the same issue as seen in;

[Red pixels on Mojave and Catalina Dark Mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338319/red-pixels-on-mojave-and-catalina-dark-mode/339250?noredirect=1#comment545421_339250)

Here is my video: https://youtu.be/sBlje8U9yJk

Anybody know anything about this?

Comment: Please describe in words what issue you mean. Just linking to a video means people have to go offsite to even know what you are asking.

Comment: @Tetsujin, My apologies! I have taken a photo of it and uploaded it to the post!